# Dockerfile: no such file or directory (java build)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm following this (https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/ )tutorial from the official website and for some reason the command `doker build` always gives me this problem.

I created new Folder in Desktop.
inside of it i created file that called `Dockerfile`, and another file that called `.dockerignore` as in the tutorial. then i opened the cmd in the same folder and try to run the command:  `docker build .`, `docker build --tag java-docker .`, `docker build -t java-docker .` , `docker build -t java-docker -f Dockerfile .`  but i always get this failure message

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount511906494/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

what I'm missing and doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Windows system, check if the name of Dockerfile has no extension.

[image: Example:]

Also, check that you are in the right folder before running the command line:

```
docker build -t java-docker .
```

Comment: You was right, i save the Dockerfile as txt instead of "all type"